# How to access the PC's resources through a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, dos

Is there a way to access the computer's physical resources like its Memory, Processor Speed and System type through batch programming (DOS)?

Comment: What do you mean by "access the...resources"? Access them how? What do you want to *do* to/with them?

Comment: I just want to know(get) its value, that's what I meant with access...

Comment: Do you really mean DOS or a command prompt in Windows?

Comment: any ideas on how to do it? or is it possible to do? I'm thinking of getting these values through a batch file and have our logic based on the values returned, if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **wmic** command might get you what you need.

Here are a couple of examples:

```
C:\> wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory
TotalPhysicalMemory
259497984

C:\> wmic cpu get name,MaxClockSpeed
MaxClockSpeed  Name
2393           Intel Celeron processor
2393           Intel Celeron processor

C:\> wmic os get Name
Microsoft Windows XP Professional|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1
```

More Examples:

http://people.virginia.edu/~rtg2t/winadmin/wmic.html

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/using_wmic.mspx?mfr=true

http://blog.commandlinekungfu.com/2009/09/episode-61-just-sit-right-back-youll.html

Comment: I'm just wondering if WMIC works inside a batch file or not? Or does it only work via CMD but not in a batch file? Hope I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, you should have no issue running WMIC from a .bat file. If you just want to dump the output to the screen you should have no troubles. However, parsing the WMIC output may be a chore.